# In PactBroker, how can I view “Webhooks” column - New PactBroker Version

Tags: pact, pact-broker

I setup my pact broker with docker, but I found no Webhooks column there. how can I get the column. I used the latest images pull from dius/pact-broker.

Comment: Can you please provide more information - version of the image, picture of the screens you are seeing/expecting etc.? Have you published pacts?

Comment: thanks Matthew, I pulled the latest image from 
https://hub.docker.com/r/dius/pact-broker/builds/.  and I have published pacts in my pacts server. but without Webhooks column.

Comment: I don't know how to paste picture here. instead, I paste to screens in my note: [link](http://note.youdao.com/noteshare?id=bc241fd3bdb98bb1b8c342dad1f48622)

Comment: here is the link: http://note.youdao.com/noteshare?id=bc241fd3bdb98bb1b8c342dad1f48622

Comment: We need to update the docker image with the latest gem. We'll try and get it done today.

Comment: Ok, I've updated the docker image. Made sure you get the one with the build code bsngvngsxz3e9dkriakes37

Comment: Thanks Beth! I got the Webhooks column with the latest image.